# How to extract .tar.bz2 directly? (avoiding a folder creation)

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, tar, extract

I always extract this kind of files using on the route where I want those files:

```
# tar -xvf file.tar.bz2
```

But it always creates a `folder` called "file" (for this example) and stores all inside it.

I've never had problem with that, but now I need to avoid that folder and simply extract everything in the route where I want all to be.

I've been reading the `man tar` (manual) .. but I still can't find an specific atribute that makes this.

How can I do that? (`All in terminal`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

tar does not create a folder called *file*; the folder *file* is stored in the tarball. This is because the tarball was creating with the command

```
tar cf foo.tar.bz2 foo
```

rather than

```
cd foo
tar cf foo.tar.bz2 .
```

According to [man tar](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?tar), you can use the switch `--strip-components` (`--strip-path` in older versions) to override this.

To strip a single leading folder, use this command:

```
tar xvf file.tar.bz2 --strip-components 1
```

Comment: Great! It worked perfectly! .. If I have more than a single folder inside the .tar file and use the `--strip-components 1` what does it do? .. or can I specify which folder to unpack?

Comment: It removes the first component of every file, i.e., `foo/bar/baz` will get extracted to `./bar/baz`. If that's not desired, you have to use several tar commands. Before unpacking, you can execute `tar tf file.tar.bz2` to see exactly where the files would get extracted.